# Jquery - dynamic div counter inside another dynamic div counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, counter

This is a slightly unusual one and one I can't seem to get my head around in terms of the logic needed.

I have a div that is dynamically added and this has a counter associated as this can be created multiple times and all need to be uniquely referenced for inputs.

Inside these divs is another set of divs that are dynamically created and again need to be counted individually for inputs. These internal divs have to have a local counter to the master div e.g:

```
<div id="master1">
    <div id="master1sub1">
    <div id="master1sub2">
    <div id="master1sub3">
</div>
<div id="master2">
    <div id="master2sub1">
    <div id="master2sub2">
</div>
```

As I am unable to predict how many masters and how many subs each master would have I am unsure how to count these dynamically.

Can anyone help?

Kind Regards,
Eamon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop them like so:

```
$("[id^=master]").each(function() {
    //looping parent divs
    $(this).children("div").each(function() {
        //looping sub divs
    });
});
```

Ideally, you would just add a common class to all parents, such as `class="parent-counter"` and a class to all child counters (`class="child-counter"`) and them count them that way

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will give it a go. Can I ask, what does the square brackets dictate? How could I use the class counter?

Comment: Square brackets are attribute selectors, what do you mean "How could I use the class counter?"

Comment: Sorry misread your comment, I thought you were counting the class but thats not what you are suggesting.

Comment: I may be missing something sorry but how does it count each child div?

Comment: `$(this).children("div").` -- targets all children divs of the original selector and loops them - if you only need the count just do `var count = $(this).children("div").length`

Comment: perfect, thats the missing piece of the puzzle I believe. I need the count for the master and the child independently.